# How to make default value null in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm making register form in laravel, first I create the migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

I want first to register name, email and password without first_name and last_name, but when I click register it gives me error that first_name and last_name don't have default values..so how to make default values null, because I want to update that columns later.

Comment: are you rolling back and running migration again or is a new migration to change the values? also which sql version do you have?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
$table->string('first_name')->default('DEFAULT');
```

edit: if the default value is supposed to be null, make it nullable instead.

```
$table->string('first_name')->nullable();
```

Comment: it gives me again the same error, i've tried that before

Comment: sorry. of course, if the default value should be null, you have to make the column nullable instead.

Comment: nothing, again the same error, i've tried `default(null)`, `nullable()`, `nullable()->default(null)` and always the same..

Comment: you did migrate:rollback and migrate again right ? can we have a look on the error message ?

Answer (score 5):

In Laravel 5.8 you can try it in migration script as below;

```
public function up()
{
    if (Schema::hasTable('table_name')) {
        Schema::table('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('column_name')->nullable();
        });
    }
}
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations

Answer (score 2):

As per Laravel 8 there are 2 simple solutions.

1. If you want a default value instead of `NULL` you can do as follow in migration schema:

   `$table->string('total')->default('0');`

This means that the default value will be `0`.

2. If you want a NULL value you can do as follow in your schema:
   `$table->string('total')->nullable();`

Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

I'm making register form in laravel, first I create the migration
If you want a default value instead of NULL you can do as follow in migration schema:

> ```
> $table->string('name')->nullable();
>
> $table->string('name')->nullable()->default('NULL');
>
> $table->string('name')->nullable()->default(NULL);
>
> $table->string('name')->nullable()->default();
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can make `first_name` & `last_name` as `nullable`:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('first_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

When you use the `nullable()` method on a field, that field will default to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

```
->default('NULL')->nullable(true)
```

empirically...